# How to make xPage JavaScript return @Unique() in Lotus Notes format?

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes

Here is the SSJS row:

```
var tmpID = @Unique();
```

But it returns unique string in following format:

```
1sghsekw3hwgh
hswhstky3hts0
```

And the length is not consistent. It can be 11 or 12 or 13 characters.
I'd like it be in Lotus Notes format, like (user initials and some random number):

```
ATFY-1RE5YU
DGGH-9VE5KX
```

Or do you know any other way to generate an unique string value with a fixed length?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

John,

I believe you can achieve that with `session.evaluate(“@Unique”)`

Comment: Perfect answer.  You can also do this in Java.  @Unique() is just about the only @formula in XPages I ever use but I use it a LOT!  :)

Comment: Cheers David, I was actually reminded about the answer from your xpages cheetsheet!

John, if you wanted to take a look, you can grab a copy at the link below, it's great for jogging my memory whenever I'm having a blank mind moment (often!)

http://www.notesin9.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/01/XPagesCheatSheet-11x17-v1.pdf